# remove "category" string from url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I have this url now:

```
http://www.example.com/menu_name/category_name/article-title/
```

How can I remove the "category_name" from url so the result is:

```
http://www.example.com/menu_name/article-title/
```

I've tried some methods I found in google but nothing seem to work.. I'm using Joomla 3.4.x and core joomla SEF..

Can somebody give me a hand on this. Thank you

Comment: You want to the redirect the browser to that new URL or just build it? Now I'm kind of lost in the thought that you probably just want to configure Joomla to do that instead of creating a code to get such URL, the first one sounds a bit more like it. Even tho both are possible.

Comment: How is i that you are making the menu link? THe menu name should be the only name showing. Unfortunately because you could potentially have the identical article title in different categories Joomla is sometimes forced to use the category name. You may want to use an advanced SEF manager.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1/$3 [L,QSA]
```

"Match anything that isn't a slash, followed by a slash, then anything that isn't a slash, followed by a slash, then anything that isn't a slash; replace that with the first and third components."